# Extract name of dataframe within a map function

Tags: r, purrr

I want to extract the name of a dataframe in a map function.
Therefore I've created 3 example dataframes:

```
name_df1<-data.frame()
name_df2<-data.frame()
name_df3<-data.frame()
```

With this code I get what I want:

```
deparse(substitute(name_df1))
[1] "name_df1"
```

And now I'm trying to put this code in a map function to extract the name of all 3 dataframes:

But first I am creating a list of all dataframes, which is nessesary to run the map-function:

```
list_dfs<-ls()
[1] "list_dfs" "name_df1" "name_df2" "name_df3"
```

And here is my map-function:

```
map(mget(list_dfs), function(x)
  deparse(substitute(x)))

But I get this:

$name_df1
[1] ".x[[i]]"

$name_df2
[1] ".x[[i]]"

$name_df3
[1] ".x[[i]]"
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the broader application of this? In the current scenario you get what you want doing `ls(pattern = "name_df")`

Comment: I want to create a ggplot for every dataframe. And I want to add a title with `+ labs(title =name_df1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to use `map2` here by passing name and dataframe separately

```
library(tidyverse)

list_dfs<-ls(pattern = "name_df")
map2(mget(list_dfs), list_dfs, ~ggplot(.x) + .... + labs(title = .y))
```

Comment: Thank you for this approach.  This works in my case.

Comment: But does anyone have another approach on how to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

We can ussee `imap` to do this on the `mget` returned `list` of objects as the `list` would be a named list and `imap` can extract the `.y` as the `names`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
imap(mget(list_dfs), ~  ggplot(.x) + 
                            ... +
                            labs(title = .y))
```